# AWS S3 Bucket policy/access from URL referer - access denied

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-apollo

My problem is maybe trivial, but I can't find the good example or straight answer anywhere...

**My setup:**

- Web app client written using Apollo and ReactJS
- Server/API written using Apollo, ReactJS and GraphQL
- Database: Mongoose

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to upload files via browser using my application straight to Amazon S3 bucket and have the ability to later list those files with thumbnails (if those are images) in the app.

I have everything setup nicely when it comes to uploading to S3. I'm using AWS JS SDK, have setup API key and secret, all in all, good.

**The problem:**

Everything works properly as long as my bucket is completely **public**.
But of course I don't want it to be public. This app will be for company internal use only, files or anything, can't be available to the public...

When I switch of public access to the bucket, I'm not longer able to even upload the files through my app, needless to say, I'm not able to see the files in my app...

I was trying to implement some bucket policy, that would allow files to be uploaded or seen if the referrer came from one of the IP addresses that I use to reach my app in the browser, but that did not work at all... *(IP addresses shown in my policy below are not the one I'm using of course, I change them here for privacy)*

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from 1.1.1.1:3000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::escape-dam/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://1.1.1.1:3000/*, http://1.1.1.1:4000/*, http://2.2.2.2:3000/*, http://2.2.2.2:4000/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Dream solution:**

Policy written in such a way, that my app will be able to send and receive files from S3 Bucket, without having to authorise each request. Basically, if you want to upload or request the file through the app you're allowed to, but not when trying to copy and paste the URL into the browser.

***As an addition I have to state, that because this is an ReactJS app, it does not ask for the files from S3 Bucket itself. It passes the stored URI from the database to the client side of the app, which later gets rendered with the page itself, so not the server asks S3 for the file, but the user's browser does. I hope this clarify my problem in it's entirety ;)***

I hope I'm clear here and do not overstate something trivial, but I'm pretty new when it comes to dealing with S3

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Use the `NotIpAddress` condition: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3 - the `aws:Referer` check does not protect the contents from any motivated attacker.

Comment: Thanks for that @luk2302!
This could work now, as I'm hosting my app on the private server with static IP, but would that work if I move my app to AWS as well, or other cloud hosting provider?

Comment: To answer that you need to be a lot more specific who actually accesses the bucket contents from which IP and where you are wondering about potential problems.

Comment: Ok. Well, I've tried the policy from the link and lock myself out of the console entirely xD

Also, I'm not sure if the IP address filtering would work in my case, here's why:
My application store the URI to the asset uploaded to S3 in the database. When user wants to see the asset, it's only passes the URI from database to the client side of the app. As it is a ReactJS app, the app itself is not requesting the file from the URI, the user browser does when rendering the page. I will include this into my post, but do you recon anything else that could work policy wise?

Comment: Then you now need root account credentials to get out of that situation and be more careful next time when crafting (bucket/IAM) policies :D

Comment: Luckily my boss has those ;)

Comment: Try restricting only `s3:GetObject` based on whatever, not `s3:*` for testing purposes, should make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @KubaPabis Have a look at this article for how to unlock your bucket https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-locked-the-whole-company-out-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket-1781de51e4be

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to upload from the frontend (client's browser) directly to your S3 bucket,  the best solution is to use S3 SignedURL feature.

**Uploading files:** The way it works (roughly) is to have your backend services send an upload request to S3, which then generates an upload URL (with a POST or PUT method). The backend service returns this URL to the frontend client, who can then upload directly to S3. Cost reduction and better performance (especially with transfer acceleration) are just some of the benefits.

**Downloading files:** The backend service generates and returns this URL to the frontend client, who can than use this URL to directly access/download the file.

So the only way to upload or download the files from S3 is with the signed URL. You can also set the expiration time for each URL (the duration for how long the URL is valid)

Best,
Stefan

Comment: Thanks for that @stefanN! 
As I'm already using AWS Javascript SDK and it works nicely I'm reluctant to change the backend now.
Also, the signed URL looks like something potentially dangerous, i.e. if only the database get leaked, someone can easily used the signed URL's stored in the database to get the files without any authorisation, but thanks for your input!

Comment: Also, the ideal scenario would have either the policy that allow user to upload/download the files to/from S3 only if they're doing this via the app. 
I was also thinking about creating one AWS user, that would be shared across the app between multiple users, and only that user could upload/download files, but I don't know how viable solution this would be? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So... Thank you all very much for your input!
I've found the solution by combining your answers and further digging into the S3 docs.

What I'm doing in my policy is:
*Blocking any IP other than my server* **and** *Blocking any referer other than my app URL*

Please, check my updated policy below.
If you also could tell me if this is secure enough, that would be great!
As an addition, my bucket public access settings looks like this:

```
Block all public access
 Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
 On
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
 Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies*
 On
Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies*
 On
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://1.1.1.1:3000/*",
                        "http://1.1.1.1:4000/*",
                        "http://2.2.2.2:3000/*",
                        "http://2.2.2.2:4000/*"
                    ]
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.1.1.1",
                        "2.2.2.2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) + OAI ( origin access identity) with bubket policy that only allows access to OAI, [check out policy from docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-cloudfront).
In this way request coming from cloudfront can only access your bucket.
another benefit cloudfront offer is caching on edge locations, which improves latency and reduce your cost for number of request on s3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EH1HDMB1FH2TC"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```